# CSS: spaces between list items that are floated left

Tags: html, css

I'm new, so please bear with me.

I made a navigation menu using ul's and li's: [here is my jsfiddle of the menu](http://jsfiddle.net/ejj94xd4/)

My problem was it had white spaces between the menu's... and the drop down menu's

I'm quite confused which part of the code was doing it. I even added clear all default margin and padding in my css. I'm guessing its the html? If so,
how do you normally remove the unwanted spacing?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 110px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is only one mistake. just remove

```
`border: 1px solid white;`
```

and add

```
 `border: none;`
```

your final code is

```
ul li{
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    width: 110px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
 }
```

Comment: omfg... thanks! !
that was very dumb of me. i added it there at first. 
to help me visualize.. but later forgot about it.

now the code makes so much sense now :D

Comment: Thanks Buddy, If you like my answer, support me. just click one right sign

Answer (score 1):

It's not `margin`, it comes from your `border: 1px solid white;`

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul{

    list-style: none;

}

ul li{
    background-color: black;
    /* border: 1px solid white; --- Here it is */
    width: 110px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}


ul li:hover ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejj94xd4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

just Update this css code

```
ul li{
    background-color: black;
    width: 110px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

it will remove white space between ul li

Comment: thank you so much guys.. was the right decision to ask here..
i was actually hesitant to ask experts, because this was too basic :D
thanks again!